# ShellExecute hangs opening new browser window if default is Chrome or IE

Tags: vb6, shellexecute, default-browser

I used this code (from MSDN) to open the default browser.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
                            Lib "shell32.dll" _
                            Alias "ShellExecuteA"( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                            ByVal lpFile As String, _
                            ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                            ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                            ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
                            As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim r As Long
   r = ShellExecute(0, "open", "http://www.microsoft.com", 0, 0, 1)
End Sub
```

It works fine for IE and chrome only if an instance is already open, it then just ads a tab
and returns the requested page.

If there is no instance already open a new one is created but the page never loads and eventually times out.

Only firefox seems to work OK in both scenarios.

I then tried a technique (detailed [here](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_get_associated_program.html)) where I created a temporary htm file in order to find the associated application with a view to then using using one of the Shell calls below:

```
Shell "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe https://www.google.co.uk/", vbNormalFocus

 Shell "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe https://www.google.co.uk/", vbNormalFocus

 Shell "C:\Users\Kjack\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe https://www.google.co.uk/", vbNormalFocus
```

This time both FF and IE worked but chrome still had the same problem.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

**EDIT to add details about OS and browser versions :**

OS : Windows Vista Home Basic 32 bit

FireFox       20.0.1

IE                 9.0.8112.16421

Opera         12.15  Build 1748

Chrome       26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: As you suspect particular browser, could you please provide more details about your environment: OS version, browsers' versions?

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov. Thanks for your suggestion, I've just done that

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov    Sorry my last comments wasn't very clear. I mean't to say that I have edited my question as per your suggestion

Answer (score 7):

Since Win2k & Me arrived you also have a clean COM-based interface for this.  It offers Unicode support without gyrations:

[Shell.ShellExecute method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .ShellExecute "http://www.microsoft.com"
    End With
```

That example lets all of the optional parameters (including the verb) default.  As already pointed out in Ken White's answer you want the verb to default in this case.

Comment: This works great for Internet explorer, Firefox and Opera but chrome still exhibits the same symptoms even after an uninstall/reinstall. It's very disappointing because it looks like I won't be able to just call up the default browser (chrome tells the user my website is unresponsive) which will annoy people whose default browser isn't Internet Explorer. Also the Opera download was tiny compared to chrome and looking at my installed programs chrome uses up about 6 times as much disk space as either Opera or Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes the assumption that there is an `open` verb assigned to the `http:` protocol, and there's no guarantee that it has been by the browser's installation.

Instead, just leave the verb empty. If you don't specify one, Windows will use whatever the default action is for the protocol or file association.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim r As Long
   r = ShellExecute(0, "", "http://www.microsoft.com", 0, 0, 1)
End Sub
```

Tip: You can see what the default action is for a file by right-clicking it in Windows Explorer. The default action is the one at the top of the context menu that's displayed in **bold** text.

Comment: Unfortunately, leaving the verb empty made no difference. Also as it happens the default action for chrome on my computer is 'open'. I did not know that tip for finding that out before, thanks. I tried uninstalling and re-installing chrome but it made no difference, even though this time chrome was installed under program files. I also installed Opera and that works fine. So it seems to be a chrome issue?

Answer (score 1):

This will open the default Browser (e.g. Chrome) without hanging:

VB6:

```
Call Shell("explorer """ & sURL & """", vbNormalFocus)
```

Or try this:

```
Dim objShell As Object
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call objShell.Run("explorer """ & sURL & """", vbNormalFocus)
```